# How to prove the statement: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} z_n=0 \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z_n|=0$ for a sequence of complex numbers

Tags: limits, analysis, complex-numbers

I need to prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} z_n=0 \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z_n|=0$.

For the forward implication, I have assumed that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n=0$, so I can state that for a $z_n = a_n+ib_n$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$ **and** $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=0$.
Next, I wrote (not sure the logic is sound here):
$${\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z_n|^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n^2+b_n^2)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n^2 + \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n^2=0\cdot0+0\cdot0}$$ from above, and as such, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z_n|=0$.

For the backward implication I am less sure. Can I state that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|z_n|=0$, then $|z_n|<1$, so that $a_n^2+b_n^2 < 1$? Even if I can, I'm not sure where to go so if there is a better way to tackle this, any pointers would also be appreciated.

Comment: One way to argue is to use that $|a_n|, |b_n| \le |z_n|$... Do you see how you might use that?

Comment: Hint: the definitions are literally identical

Comment: Begin with: what is the definition of convergence for a sequence of complex numbers?  Your proof will depend on that definition.  Also, mention "complex numbers" in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Why is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$?

Comment: Expanding the suggestion of @Lorago, if you write down the $\epsilon$,$\delta$ definition of $\lim z_n=0$ and the $\epsilon$,$\delta$ definition of $\lim |z_n|=0$ then, after applying a few identities to simplify, the results are symbol for symbol identical to each other.

Comment: From the second sentence of the post I assumed you wanted to prove that $\lim_n |z_n| = 0$ if and only if $\lim_n a_n = 0$ and $\lim_n b_n = 0$ (in other words - that the product topology and the Euclidean topology coincide). In other words, that your definition of $\lim_n z_n = 0$ is that  $\lim_n a_n = 0$ and $\lim_n b_n = 0$. This would be atypical, and if that's not the case, then you should ignore my comment and Lee and Lorago's comments are probably what you should pay attention to.

Comment: @Lorago so by using the definition of converge to state that the left-hand side reads $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\ge N:|z_n-0|=|z_n|<\epsilon$ and the right hand side read: $\forall\epsilon >0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\ge N:||z_n|-0|=|z_n|<\epsilon$ which are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another approach: $"\to"$ 
Assume $z_n \to 0$. Then $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N: n > N, \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \Rightarrow ||z_n| - 0| = ||z_n|| = |z_n| = |z_n - 0| < \varepsilon $ 
 So $|z_n| \to 0.$

Same for: "$\gets$" 
Assume $|a_n| \to 0$ Then $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N: n > N, \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \Rightarrow |z_n - 0| = |z_n| = ||z_n|| = ||z_n| - 0| < \varepsilon $ 
 So $z_n \to 0.$